# What is this "very, very powerful article" that Trump is referring to vis à vis the Kurds?

Tags: donald-trump, kurdistan

Trump [said](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/video/2019/oct/10/donald-trump-says-kurds-didnt-help-us-with-normandy-video) in a press conference on Oct 10 (or so), referring to the Kurds:

> as someone wrote in this very, very powerful article today, they didn't help us in the second world war, they didn't help us with Normandy [...]

What's the article he is referring to? Of course, we need an educated guess, but if his time reference is correct, there can't be that many candidates...

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, the Kurds did fight with the allies in WW2. For example see this [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2019/10/10/actually-president-trump-some-kurds-did-fight-world-war-ii/).

Answer (score 40):

Apparently the press was curious too... After [a hint](https://www.thejournal.ie/trump-defends-syria-decision-saying-kurds-didnt-help-with-normandy-4844485-Oct2019/) that it was a Townhall article, it didn't take long to locate it. It's penned by Kurt  Schlichter, and it does [say](https://townhall.com/columnists/kurtschlichter/2019/10/08/critics-aghast-as-trump-keeps-word-about-no-more-wars-n2554328) pretty much what Trump said:

> I generally like the Kurds. I generally dislike the Turks. But they’ve been killing each other for a long time and no one has yet offered a sufficient reason why America should stick its troops in the crossfire between them. [...]
>
> The Kurds helped destroy ISIS, true. It’s also true that the Kurds would have fought ISIS anyway, since the psycho caliphate was right next door. Let’s be honest – the Kurds didn’t show up for us at Normandy or Inchon or Khe Sanh or Kandahar.